# Will the Radeon HD 7640G be supported by the new AMDGPU kernel driver on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a laptop with an AMD A8-4500M with 7640G discrete-class graphics and since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 I am getting less FPS in games since I cannot use the old FGLRX driver.

According to http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMDGPU-SI-Next-4.9 the new AMDGPU open source kernel driver is coming to Southern Islands (HD 7000) GPUs.

According to http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-7640G.69836.0.html my laptop's GPU is mix between the newer Southern Islands and the older Northern Islands (VLIW4) architecture.

So will my laptop's GPU work with the new AMDGPU driver ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the integrated GPU in your laptop is actually [based on a pre-GCN architecture](http://laptopmedia.com/video-card/amd-radeon-hd-7640g/) which AMD has no intention of supporting in AMDGPU.

Your laptop may come with a "discrete" dual graphics solution that is based on GCN (e.g. [8750M](http://laptopmedia.com/video-card/amd-radeon-hd-8750m-hd-7640g-2gb-ddr3/)), but I suspect there would be problems with using this on Linux given that the integrated graphics does not support the AMDGPU driver.

Comment: So , it won't probably work ? The GPU cores are based on the older Northern Islands but it uses the display connectors from the newer GCN. Maybe I could try adding the GPUs PCID to the new kernel driver and seeing if it boots (since only GPU cores are Northern Islands)